# Facebook ads - Error creating Ads creative

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I need to post an ad using facebook api ads and I am using the php SDK.
I can create a campaign > targeting > AdSet. When I create an Ad Creative I get the error:

```
#errorUserMessage: "Ads creative post was created by an app that is in development mode. It must be in public to create this ad."
```

It states that I cannot create an Ads creative in development mode. But to get out of development mode I need to show the working application to the face.

I researched the bug and found that there is a facebook bug. They have Ads creative created manually and enter the code when publishing the ad. But I had the same error when I went to create manually. Can someone help me?

I don't know what else to do to solve this. Please help me.

Comment: What status do you post? Have you tried to create Ads with 'PAUSED' status?

Comment: same case with me , if i use the api in the development mode than its giving me the same error, and if i switch the application to the live mood then its giving error of access token with the ads management permission , anybody can help

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by sending the application for analysis. In the request for review for approval I recorded a video explaining the situation and asked facebook to release. I informed that it was not possible to record the video showing the stream, because facebook itself does not let use the application in development mode. In two days they released my app.